# ¿porque me dice que la propiedad path no esta definida (multer)?

Tags: nodejs, express, multer

Estoy en `movies.js` y mi ruta me saca este error, estoy intentando usar multer para subir una imagen por película, solo una pero me dice que mi path no esta definido.

> error: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'path' of undefined
>       at router.put

ya probé que `movieImg: req.body.file.path` pero tampoco funciona.
no se que esta pasando también tengo un error de server status 500 ayuda por favor. 
agradezco de antemano a la persona que me ayude, saludos y gracias.

```js
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'img/');
      },
      filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
      }
    });

    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
      if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(null, false);
      }
    }

    const upload = multer({ 
        storage: storage, 
        limits: { fileSize: 1024*1024*5 },
        fileFilter: fileFilter 
    });

    router.put("/:id", upload.single('movieImg'), [auth], async (req, res) => {
      const { error } = validate(req.body);
      if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

      const genre = await Genre.findById(req.body.genreId);
      if (!genre) return res.status(400).send("Invalid genre.");

      const movie = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {
          title: req.body.title,
          genre: {
            _id: genre._id,
            name: genre.name
          },
          numberInStock: req.body.numberInStock,
          dailyRentalRate: req.body.dailyRentalRate,
          movieImg: req.file.path
        },
        { new: true }
      );

      if (!movie)
        return res.status(404).send("The movie with the given ID was not found.");

      res.send(movie);
    });
```

Comment: ¿Que tal si haces un `console.log(req.file)` para ver los atributos y valores de dicho objeto? En el caso que sea `undefined` es porque el middleware de  `multer` no está realizando la tarea asignada y deberías buscar el porqué.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya me aparecen las imagenes en una carpeta llamada img/ en el backend pero no se como hacer para guardar en la carpeta public de react y en el frontend me da un error 404 cuando intento subir las imagenes.

Comment: @gbianchi como hago para recibir las imagenes en react en la carpeta public?